# Selenium + PhantomJS in Scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scrapy, phantomjs

I am trying to use Selenium and PhantomJS to get the dynamic content of a website. Here's my code

```
class judge(Spider):
    name = "judge"
    start_urls = ["http://wenshu.court.gov.cn/List/List?sorttype=1&conditions=searchWord+2+AJLX++%E6%A1%88%E4%BB%B6%E7%B1%BB%E5%9E%8B:%E6%B0%91%E4%BA%8B%E6%A1%88%E4%BB%B6"]

    def init_driver(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        return driver 

    def parse(self,response):
        driver = self.init_driver()
        driver.get(self.start_urls[0])
        sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
        self.logger.info(u'---------------Parsing----------------')
        print sel.xpath("//div[@class='dataItem'][1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[@class='wstitle']/a/text()").extract()
        self.logger.info(u'---------------success----------------')
```

When I try my script with `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`, sel.xpath("//div[@class='dataItem'] gives the desired content and everything works fine. But when I instead use `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()`, sel.xpath("//div[@class='dataItem'] is empty. I have try to use WebDriverWait after `driver.get()` to make the page fully loaded, but it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried taking a screenshot while using phantom to verify phantom is actually loading in the dynamic content?

Comment: I've checked the response by `response.page_source` and it seems that phantom does not load the dynamic content. I have no idea about what is going wrong....

Comment: @Y_KL Were you able to sort it out

Comment: @Volatil3 I think the problem is that PhantomJS is not compatible with all web pages. Please Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('add your directory of phantomjs here')
```